# Compare two columns both of which are concatenated, and append missing items from one to the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to compare country codes in two columns, both of which store multiple values in a single cell, one is comma separated strings and the other is Python lists.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| BB,CC | [AA,BB] |
| AA,BB | [AA,BB] |

I need to append elements from column B to column A, with no duplicates, and the order must remain unchanged. The expected result will be.

| Column C |
| --- |
| BB,CC,AA |
| AA,BB |

I tried to extract the missing items by
`df['Column B'].apply(lambda x:[i if i not in df['Column A'] else None for i in x])`

But unfortunately it seems that df['Column A'] here gives me the entire Series instead of the corresponding row in this Series, so it does not return the expected result.

I know a workaround is to split Column A into lists too and concat lists of two columns, then de-depulicate it using set(), but set will potentially change the order, which will cause a trouble for my next task, so I didn't go down this way.

Can someone help?

Comment: Probably you've forgotten to add the axis param while using .apply method. In order to execute your funcs row-wise try to add the param axis=1.

Comment: Single series doesn't support axis=1, it somehow treats it as an argument for the lambda function, even if I put it before the lambda. TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'.

I select two columns as a dataframe and tried again, got another error - TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 1):

Have figured it out and want to share the resolution.

```
def func(string, codes): # e.g. string='AA|CC', codes=['AA', 'BB'] >> return ['BB']
    missing_codes = []
    for c in codes:
        if c not in string:
            missing_codes.append(c)
    return missing_codes
```

Next, apply and broadcast the function, return a series of missing codes.

```
missing_codes = pd.concat([df['Column A'], df['Column B']], axis=1).apply(lambda x:func(x['Column A'], x['Column B']), axis=1)
```

Finally, concatenate the series to column A

```
df['Column C'] = (df['Column A'] + ',' + missing_codes.apply(lambda x:','.join(x))).str.strip(',')
```